# How do I animate the changes of a single data point's color using matplolib.animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change a color of the single data point (101th entry of df) in the scatter plot. How do I animate the changes using matplotlib.animation?

First, this is what original scatter plot is:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animat
fig ,ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(15, 8)

groups = df.groupby('Name')
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.SepalWidth, 
            group.SepalLength, 
            marker='o', 
            linestyle='',
            label=name)
ax.legend(fontsize=10) # legend position
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Sabotaged Iris Data', fontsize=20)
plt.annotate('Sabotaged Data', xy=(3.31,6.305), xytext=(3.5,6.5), arrowprops = dict(facecolor ='black', shrink = 0.04))
plt.xlabel('Sepal Width', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Sepal Length', fontsize=14)
```

And now I am trying to change the colors as frame changes (maybe red, orange, yellow, pink, purple), but I can't think of how to fill up the update function:

```
def update(frame):
   # ???

ani = animat.FuncAnimation(fig, update,
                           frames=360, 
                           interval=0.01,
                           blit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are mixing the old interface (such as `plt.plot`) with the newer [object-oriented interface](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/) (which would use `ax.plot`). It's best to stick with one interface for code that is executed together.

You can't give an arbitrary color to an individual dot from a scatter plot. But you can create a new scatter plot with just one dot, and change its color inside the `update` function. If one constantly creates new elements inside the animation, the system's memory can get quite full. Therefore, usually a previously created element is updated.

Also note that `FuncAnimation`'s interval is measured in milliseconds. Changes in less than 50 ms will be hard to notice (and probably the system can't regenerate that fast).

```py
import matplotlib.animation as animat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df.rename(columns={'species': 'Name', 'sepal_width': 'SepalWidth', 'sepal_length': 'SepalLength'}, inplace=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_dpi(100)
fig.set_size_inches(15, 8)

groups = df.groupby('Name')
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.SepalWidth,
            group.SepalLength,
            marker='o',
            linestyle='',
            label=name)
ax.legend(fontsize=10)  # legend position
ax.set_title('Scatter Plot of Sabotaged Iris Data', fontsize=20)
sabotaged = (3.31, 6.305)
ax.annotate('Sabotaged Data', xy=sabotaged, xytext=(3.5, 6.5), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.04))

ax.set_xlabel('Sepal Width', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Sepal Length', fontsize=14)
scatter_dot = ax.scatter(*sabotaged, s=90, fc='turquoise', zorder=3)
# scatter_circle = ax.scatter(*sabotaged, s=100, fc='none', ec='red', zorder=3)

def update(frame):
    colors = ['crimson', 'darkorange', 'lime', 'cornflowerblue', 'purple', 'fuchsia']
    scatter_dot.set_color(colors[frame % len(colors)])
    return scatter_dot,

ani = animat.FuncAnimation(fig, update,
                           frames=360,
                           interval=2000,
                           blit=True)
plt.show()
```